# расстояние между словами

Tags: html, css

Как увеличить расстояние между словами

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    
}
.wrapper {
    height: 1400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
/* Шапка */
.image_time{
    display: flex;
    
}
.hi_vremya{
    align-self: center;
    margin: 5px;
}


.hi_icons{
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
}
.text{
    text-align: right;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.hi{
    
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.hi_row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
.hi_body{
    align-self: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'FuturaPT'
    display:flex;
}
/* Шапка */
.footer{
    background-color: bisque;
    
}
.footer_row{
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.footer_text{
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main1.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="content">
           <div class="hi">
               <div class="container">
                   <div class="hi_row">
                       <div class="image_time">
                       <div class="hi_image">
                           <img src="cart/icons/back.png" alt="" height="70" width="100">
                       </div>
                       <div class="hi_vremya">
                           Время работы <br>
                           Пн-Вс: 08.00-22.00
                       </div>
                       </div>
                       
                       <div class="hi_body">
                           Пекарни
                           Акции
                           Преимущества
                           Контакты  
                       </div>
                       
                       
                           <div class="hi_icons">
                               <img src="cart/icons/telefon.png" alt="">
                               <img src="cart/icons/korzina.png" alt="">
                               <div class="nomer_text">
                                   <div class="nomer">
                                      +7 (937) 937-11-10 
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="text">
                                       <u>Заказать звонок</u>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                               <img src="cart/icons/vhod.png" alt="">
                           </div>
                       
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="footer">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="footer_row">
                   <div class="footer_text">
                       Государевы пекарни
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

(Пекарни, Акции, Преимущества, Контакты)

Comment: на отдельные блоки разбить каждое слово и задать `margin`

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-spacing

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pogyzQL